# Loading charset map: no such file or directory, KOI8-T

Tags: microsoft-windows, emacs24

Today I suddenly started getting the above error whenever I try to save a file in emacs 24.5 on Windows 10.

Here is my full list of messages:

```
Loading c:/Users/Psalm3_3/GDrive/Tools/Emacs-24.5/site-lisp/flymake.el (source)...done
Loading c:/Users/Psalm3_3/GDrive/Tools/Emacs-24.5/site-lisp/csharp-mode.el (source)...
Loading c:/Users/Psalm3_3/GDrive/Tools/Emacs-24.5/site-lisp/csharp-mode.el
../site-lisp/csharp-mode.el: `flet' is an obsolete macro (as of 24.3); use either `cl-flet' or `cl-letf'. [2 times]
../site-lisp/csharp-mode.el: (lambda (item) ...) quoted with ' rather than with #'
Done loading c:/Users/Psalm3_3/GDrive/Tools/Emacs-24.5/site-lisp/csharp-mode.el
Loading c:/Users/Psalm3_3/GDrive/Tools/Emacs-24.5/site-lisp/csharp-mode.el (source)...done
Loading c:/Users/Psalm3_3/GDrive/Tools/Emacs-24.5/site-lisp/desktop.el (source)...
Eager macro-expansion failure: (error "(alist-get (quote display) filtered) is not a valid place expression")
Loading c:/Users/Psalm3_3/GDrive/Tools/Emacs-24.5/site-lisp/desktop.el (source)...done
Loading c:/Users/Psalm3_3/GDrive/Tools/Emacs-24.5/site-lisp/session.el (source)...done
Loading c:/Users/Psalm3_3/GDrive/Tools/Emacs-24.5/site-lisp/xah-math-input.el (source)...done
Loading c:/Users/Psalm3_3/GDrive/Tools/Emacs-24.5/site-lisp/unicode-fonts.el (source)...done
Loading c:/Users/Psalm3_3/GDrive/Tools/Emacs-24.5/site-lisp/php-mode.el (source)...done
zlib library not found
notes.txt has auto save data; consider M-x recover-this-file
Desktop: File "c:/c" no longer exists.
Can't guess python-indent-offset, using defaults: 4 [39 times]
Wrote c:/Users/Psalm3_3/.emacs.d/.emacs.desktop.lock
Desktop: 1 frame, 55 buffers restored, 1 failed to restore.
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
Saving file c:/Users/Psalm3_3/GDrive/Resources/Courses/StanMachLrn/notes.txt...
find-coding-systems-region: Loading charset map: no such file or directory, KOI8-T
```

Why would emacs suddenly want to use Cyrillic text?  Does anyone have any suggestions?  TIA.

**UPDATE:**

Started running from an older emacs setup that didn't have AUCTEX installed, which doesn't give me the error, so it appears to be a problem with this:  https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/

Comment: With your update, this might not be necessary, but just in case: does this issue still occur when you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`? If not, please try to [bisect your init file](//meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/a/204/675).

Comment: OK, thanks for the idea.  It is weird, because emacs was working great for me the last few days.  Then this error just popped up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I had missed these files when moving emacs to a new directory:

```
CNS-3.map
CP1252.map 
CP932-2BYTE.map 
EBCDICUK.map 
IBM1004.map 
IBM290.map 
IBM420.map 
IBM861.map 
IBM874.map 
KOI8-T.map 
MIK.map 
TIS-620.map 
calccard.pdf 
fr-refcard.pdf 
byte-opt.el 
cconv.el 
cl-macs.el 
cl-seq.el cl.el 
eieio-core.el 
eieio-opt.el 
ert-x.el 
gv.el 
package.el 
timer.el 
erc-match.el 
Punct-b5.el 
TONEPY.el 
tsang-b5.el 
ob-haskell.el 
ob-io.el 
org-bibtex.el 
ox-man.el 
url-nfs.el
```

Thankfully, this means that I can now use auctex again.