# Loading charset map: No such file or directory, JISX0208

Tags: debugging, error, save

Trying to save files I have suddenly started recieving the following error:

> Loading charset map: No such file or directory, JISX0208

In  *Messages* this is reported as:

> find-coding-systems-region: Loading charset map: No such file or directory, JISX0208
> Mark set

I'm using GNU Emacs 27.2 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.20, cairo version 1.16.0) running on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

I can't find obviously similar previous questions and am stuck. Would be great to get any suggestions.

** Update **

When I try to export org mode files using the Org export dispatcher I see the following error:

> OpenDocument export failed: Invalid specification of styles.xml file: nil

Comment: Did you build Emacs yourself? That file is part of Emacs, perhaps the ubuntu package misses out some files?

Comment: I installed using apt. Removing it and installing emacs 28.1 fixed the problem. I remain curious how tihis would come about though.

Comment: Please update the question to make clear that you fixed your problem and you just want to get an explanation. Make clear what you're asking.

Comment: I suspect the Ubuntu emacs-27 package was 'optimized' by removing 'unnecessary' files. But I don't have Ubuntu running anywhere to try.

Comment: Similar  problem: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24282/loading-charset-map-no-such-file-or-directory-koi8-t

Answer (score 1):

This problem recently bit me too. What likely happens it that while Emacs is running, Ubuntu has upgraded Emacs. Thus, all files in the directory `/usr/share/emacs/Y.X` (including `etc/charsets/JISX0208.map`), where `X.Y` is the old Emacs version, has been deleted and replaced with files in `/usr/share/emacs/Z.W`, where `Z.W` is the new Emacs version. Since Emacs loads most of the files it needs into memory it can take a long time for it to discover that the files it needs have disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to emacs 28.1 fixed the problem.

I remain curious how the errors would come about though. Answers with explanations would still be useful. Thanks.